# how to calculate average subtraction summation using java from degree minutes second

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate degree minute seconds using different value
ex

```
Sum
12°13'14''+12°13'14'' = 24°26'28"
Average
12°13'14''
12°13'15''
12°13'16''
average = 12°13'15''
```

in java i convert into degree decimal after that calculate sum and subtraction final result convert to degree minutes second
but i am not getting average,subtraction

Comment: Please add the code you already have

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it on your own:

You can create an object type/class with the name Coordinate.
There you can define three integers (hours, minutes, seconds).
Then you can create static util methods for adding, substracting, testing, making the average and so on.

**adding method**

```
public static Coordinate add(Coordinate one, Coordinate two){
    Coordinate sum = new Coordinate (one.degrees + two.degrees, /*and so on*/);
    sum.check();
    return sum;
}
```

**checking method**

```
public void check(){
     if(seconds > 60){
           minutes += (int) seconds/60;
           seconds = secounds%60;
     }
     if(minutes > 60){
           degrees += (int) minutes /60;
           minutes = minutes %60;
     }
}
```

for the avarage, you can write your own method. (adding then dividing and finally checking)
Hope this helps.